# German stopwords not working having special characters for solr on JBoss server

Tags: solr, jboss7.x, solr4, stop-words

I am having Solr 4 search on JBoss 7 server and trying to configure stopwords for english & german language. My configurations for stopwords are:

```
<fieldType name="text_copy" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The stopwords for above configurations are working for normal english characters, but for german special character like "könnt" it's not working.
So what should be my configs for german special characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="german/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="french/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

Try adding filter for german in your schema just after filter declaration for stopwords using **stopwords.txt** You can add as many filters as you need.